# How to save bandwidth when using QGraphicsview with X-redirection

Tags: c++, qt, x11, bandwidth, x11-forwarding

I have a large QGraphicsScene that I want to display, currently done by QGraphicsView.
When using locally everything is fine, but as soon as I use the App with ssh -X it is terribly slow. Of course some data always has to be transferred, but how could the bandwidth be saved if nothing changes, for example when only panning the image?

This is my QGraphicsView:

```
#include "graphicsview.h"
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QWheelEvent>
#include <cmath>
#include <QPixmapCache>

GraphicsView::GraphicsView(QWidget *parent) :
    QGraphicsView(parent)
{
    QPixmapCache::setCacheLimit(16777216); //did not do the trick either
    this->setMouseTracking(true);
    setTransformationAnchor(AnchorUnderMouse);
    this->setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    setScene(scene);
    background = QPixmap(8000,8000);
    qDebug() << background.rect();
    scene->setSceneRect(background.rect());
    scene->setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(background));
    show();
}

void GraphicsView::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event) {
    scale(pow(2,event->delta()/240.0), pow(2,event->delta()/240.0));
}
```